# How can a ComboBox.MatchEntry property have the `fmMatchEntryComplete` value but have the ability to overwrite the autocompletion feature?

Tags: excel, vba

My issue is that I have a listbox implanted into the combobox with the `ComboBox.List = MyArr` as the list data in the box. I was hoping it would work similarly to most of the userforms you see in other applications where typing in the combobox will display the best match with regards to the user's input, but remove the autocomplete feature when one presses the backspace button on the keyboard.

An issue arises when I try to only input a shortened version of the text. An example of this is when the pre-defined list contains the word: "SUNNIES", but I want to type in "SUN" instead. The combobox will always autocomplete into "SUNNIES" no matter what I do. But I also do not want to remove the autocomplete feature.

Below is the sample of my form:
[image]

Comment: If you type "SUN" it will suggest "SUNNIES" (if that is in your list) but then you are able to remove the rest "NIES" and you have "SUN". There is either the way to remove autocomplete or live with it. The computer cannot know that you want to stop at "SUN" and that you don't want to write "SUNNIES".

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Thanks for a split second I saw a comment that suggested using the "Delete" button in the keyboard rather than the "Backspace" and I think it's the workaround for it

Comment: Using the delete button is no workaround that is basic keyboard usage. That's exactly why there is a delete button on the keyboard.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Now I know there is a different function besides deleting files on the desktop lol. I never had a problem with most comboboxes in other userforms by other applications such as web applications forms where I just backspace the autocompletion until now

Comment: @TinMan This is only a solution if "SUN" exists in the ComboBox list. If this is a manual user input that is *NOT* in the list, the issue still remains.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there is a workaround to achieve your desired behavior using the `_KeyDown` event.

You can change the behavior of your `ComboBox1` by using this:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
    If Me.ComboBox1.SelLength > 0 And KeyCode = 8 Then
        KeyCode = 46
    End If
End Sub
```

It looks if there is a selected text and if the backspace is pressed `KeyCode = 8` if so it changes it to delete `KeyCode = 46`. If there is nothing selected it will backspace as usual.

---

#### If you want to apply this to all ComboBoxes in your UserForm …

… do the following instead of the above `_KeyDown` event.

1. Add a class module and name it `CmbClass` with the following code:

   ```
   Option Explicit

   Public WithEvents ComboBoxGroup As MSForms.ComboBox

   Private Sub ComboBoxGroup_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
       If ComboBoxGroup.SelLength > 0 And KeyCode = 8 Then
           KeyCode = 46
       End If
   End Sub
   ```
2. Add the following code to every UserForm you want to apply the behavior:

   ```
   Option Explicit

   Dim ComboBoxes() As New cmbClass

   Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
       Dim ComboBoxCount As Integer
       Dim ctl As Control
       ComboBoxCount = 0
       For Each ctl In Me.Controls
           If TypeName(ctl) = "ComboBox" Then
               ComboBoxCount = ComboBoxCount + 1
               ReDim Preserve ComboBoxes(1 To ComboBoxCount)
               Set ComboBoxes(ComboBoxCount).ComboBoxGroup = ctl
           End If
       Next ctl
   End Sub
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I added a textbox on top of the ComboBox; then hide the ComboBox when I want to add a new item to a ComboBox. I then am able a type in the TextBox new similar item. Later, I add the new item to the source data then clear the ComboBox and reload the ComboBox from the source data. Hide the TextBox and then make the ComboBox Visible.